# Sorted Sets Not updating value based on key in Redis

Tags: redis, sortedset

I am new to sorted sets in Redis (3.0.2). I basically want to update my value in sorted sets of Redis based on unique key. As of now "zadd" each time keeps on adding new values to a specific key.

As of now:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd xyz 1 "abc"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd xyz 1 "newabc"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange xyz 0 -1
1) "abc"
2) "newabc"
```

Required Output: (It should over write the xyz key's value from "abc" to "newabc"

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd xyz 1 "abc"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd xyz 1 "newabc"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange xyz 0 -1
1) "newabc"
```

Comment: Sounds like you want an ordered map of some kind. It may be sufficient to use something like `set "xyz:1" "abc"` depending on your use-case. Please add some more details :)

Answer (score 0):

A *sorted set* in Redis is a *set* when we talk about *the element*, while multiple different elements can coexist with the same *score*.

If you want that output, you'll need to design a different data model, and since I don't know your actual issue or what's your goal in your project, I won't be able to provide a clear solution.

Comment: I want to implement it for searching.. as it is there in case of instagram.

Comment: @Vaibhav Your requirement is too vague... "as instagram".... I would say that you should mark this answer as accepted and ask another and concrete question explaining your use case completely and then we're going to be able to provide you a solution.